# rich:tree selectionChangeListener does not get invoked in RichFaces 4.5.5

Tags: jsf, richfaces

The listener method, when clicked on a tree node, does not get invoked. I tried to debug the listener method in a bean but it doesn't get invoked. Is there  any alternative to the listener event which is used. Also no error is found, when clicked on the node.

RichFaces 4.5.5 and MyFaces 2.2.8 is used.

XHTML Code -

```
<rich:tree selectionChangeListener="#{testbean.selectionChanged}"
           selectionType="ajax"
           render="grid"
           value="#{testbean.rootNode}"
           var="item"
           toggleType="client">
</rich:tree>
```

Bean Code  -

```
public void selectionChanged(TreeSelectionChangeEvent event) {
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should try this atribute:

```
execute="@this"
```